# AWS Logs Output

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, logfiles

I am set up on AWS with a ubuntu instance and apache server. I want to debug my programs by sending output to the aws ssh command line interface on my local terminal. I would assume I would use the `console.log("hello world")` command in the java script in my html.

Alternatively there is a console.log file somewhere, which I can then use something like `tail -f console.log`.

Any other standard debugging methods ideas are welcome. A bit frustrating because this ought to be pretty straightforward.

For starters, if I could send any output to my terminal from any method that would be progress.

Answer (score 0):

console.log is a log file on the browser that executes the html. In Chrome, hit F12 or ctrl+shift+i. It's not a log file on the apache server.